# Parameters of a function in python

Tags: python, function, runtime

I have the code below and I would like to feel the parameters of the function map at runtime. It should be like

```
#devices = map(InputDevice, ('/dev/input/event15','/dev/input/event16'))
```

But when I try to do it at runtime, it does not work. Here is my attempt:

```
readers = ""
devices = map(InputDevice, list_devices())
for dev in devices:
   if "深" in dev.name or "Barcode" in dev.name:
      if readers == "":
         readers = "'" + dev.fn + "'"
      else:
         readers = readers + ", '" + dev.fn + "'"

devices = map(InputDevice, (readers))
```

Where readers shows exactly **'/dev/input/event15','/dev/input/event16'**, but this string does not work as parameter. I guess it does not work because of the comma. Does anyone know how can I do it?

This function is part of the evdev.

Thanks since now!
Best regards,
Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you want `readers` to be a non-string iterable.  Maybe try:

```
devices = map(InputDevice, readers.split(','))
```

This will split `readers` into a list, rather than keeping it as a string.

This still isn't particularly clean code.  Better would be to build a list in the first place:

```
readers = []
devices = map(InputDevice, list_devices())
for dev in devices:
   if "深" in dev.name or "Barcode" in dev.name:
      readers.append(dev.fn)

devices = map(InputDevice, (readers))
```